# JS fetch downloading a file: Where to place the spinner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch-api

I'm trying to download a file using fetch, I'm trying to place a spinner, but every time I place it, the fetch fails.

```
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display = 'block';

    fetch(url)
        .then(resp => resp.blob())
        .then(file => {
            if (file.size > 0) {
                const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                const a = document.createElement('a');
                a.style.display = 'none';
                a.href = url;
                a.download = filename;
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
            } else {
                $('#banner').html('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">This provider does not seem to have any data during the selected dates, if you believe there is an issue, please contact the developers</div>');
            }
              document.getElementById("loader").style.display = 'none';

        })
        .catch(() => {
            $('#banner').html('<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">This provider does not seem to have any data during the selected dates, if you believe there is an issue, please contact the developers</div>');
            document.getElementById("loader").style.display = 'none';

        });
```

The spinner is `document.getElementById("loader")`, I'm commenting it out in the production code because it makes the fetch fails.

If you click download, it starts fetching and the spinner is visible, then after a while the fetch fails, no file gets downloaded and the spinner disappears. If you comment out the spinner, everything works.

I get this error `500 internal server error`

And this momentjs warning which is irrelevant.

```
moment.min.js:1 Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
Arguments: 
[0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: 07/01/2019, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]
Error
```

I get no error if the loader does not exist.

Comment: Why are you mixing regular native JS and jQuery syntax? That seems odd. It also seems unlikely that the spinner is the source of your problems. Does the console output anything useful in terms of error messages when it fails

Comment: in your `catch` give it a parameter of `e` and `console.log` so you can see the actual error - is it just a timeout?

Comment: @mituw16 question edited to include the error.

Comment: @Adam question edited to include the error

Comment: I'm confused as heck - there's no way that commenting out the spinner prevents a 500 error.

Comment: @Adamc exactly, if I saw an actual error, I would have fixed it without asking here :P

Answer (score 0):

Stop the loader in the [`finally()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally) method of the promise.

```js
let loader = document.getElementById("loader");

// BEGIN LOADING
loader.style.display = 'block';

fetch(url)
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(file => {
    // HANDLE FILE
  })
  .catch(() => {
    // LOG ERROR
  })
  .finally(() => {
    // STOP LOADING
    loader.style.display = 'none';
  });
```

Comment: Question edited to include the error, the code above does not fix it.